# python randomly generated orders are the same

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to generate different random order in N loop, but python seems to generate same sequence. Is the code below correctly written as I am expecting?

```
import random
import time

def funcA():
    nodeCount = 10               
    order = range(0, nodeCount) 

    random.seed(0x87654321)         
    random.shuffle(order)    

    print("Shuffle order - ")
    print(order)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    cnt = 0
    while cnt < 3:     
#         random.seed(0x87654321) 
        funcA()
        time.sleep(5) 
        cnt += 1
```

Comment: Lots of stuff here.  You don't have indents on the function or the while, but assuming that's ok, you are resetting the seed each time, so the results will be the same.  For different results, ust set the seed once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is in this statement:

```
random.seed(0x87654321)
```

What this does is provide a "seed" value for the random number generator to use as random data.  Since the seed is hardcoded *right before each call to the shuffle function*, the random number generator will behave the same every time.

To fix the issue (and get different results each time you run it), simply remove this statement.  If you want to initialize it with the seed, initialize once by doing it outside of the `while` loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    cnt = 0
    random.seed(0x87654321) 
    while cnt < 3:     
        funcA()
        time.sleep(5) 
        cnt += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're seeding the random number generator with a constant. Any sequence of identical calls to the random number generator with the same seed will produce the same output. If that's not what you want, don't call `seed`.

Answer (score 1):

Call random.seed() only once, not every time before shuffle.